# ¿Es posible actualizar el valor que se muestra en un label en tiempo real usando tkinter en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
# Los botones son todos aquellos que realizan acciones sobre el programa
from tkinter import *

# Funcion de suma
def sumar():
    Suma = float(n1.get()) + float(n2.get())
    r.set(str(Suma))
    borrar()
    return Suma

def restar():
    Resta = float(n1.get()) - float(n2.get())
    r.set(str(Resta))
    borrar()
    return Resta

def producto():
    Producto = float(n1.get()) + float(n2.get())
    r.set(str(Producto))
    borrar()
    return Producto

def borrar():
    n1.set("")
    n2.set("")

# Configuracion de la raiz
root = Tk()
root.config(bd=15)

n1 = StringVar()
n2 = StringVar()
r = StringVar()

Label(root, text="Número 1").pack()
# Crear campos de texto
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=n1).pack()
Label(root, text="Número 2").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=n2).pack()
# Crear un boton
Label(root, text="").pack()
Button(root, text="Sumar", command=sumar).pack()
Button(root, text="Restar", command=restar).pack()
Button(root, text="Multiplicar", command=producto).pack()
Label(root, text="\nResultado").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=r, state="disabled").pack()

# Bucle while de la aplicacion
root.mainloop()
```

Quisiera saber si es posible, por ejemplo, realizar la suma pero sin utilizar el boton, es decir, solo agregando los datos en los Entry y que el programa, al detectar que hay valores numericos, haga la suma sin yo oprimir el boton y la muestre como en tiempo real en el label.

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es totalmente posible, la clave está en asociar una callback a ambas `SringVars` mediante su método `trace_add` que sea llamada cada vez que sena modificadas, es decir, cada vez que los campos de texto lo sean.

Ten en cuenta:

- Para poder realizar varias operaciones debes disponer de alguna forma de indicar la operación en si, bien mediante otro Entry, Radiobuttons, un Combobox, etc.
- No puedes ejecutar la operación y borrar los campos en cuanto el usuario ingrese algo o solo podrá operar con un dígito por campo:

  - O usas una estrategia algo diferente, enlazando el evento de la pulsación de a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> al último entry para que se realize la operación en ese momento.
  - Habilitas un botón que se encargue de borrar, similar a cómo funciona las calculadoras físicas.

---

```
import tkinter as tk


def borrar():
    n1.set("")
    n2.set("")
    res.set("")
    

def resolver(*_):
    if not (a:= n1.get()) or not (b:= n2.get()):
        return
    try:
        a, b = float(a), float(b)
    except ValueError:
        res.set("ERROR")
    else:
        if (operacion:= op.get()) == "suma":
            res.set(str(a + b))
        elif operacion == "resta":
            res.set(str(a - b))
        elif operacion == "mult":
            res.set(str(a + b))
        elif operacion == "div":
            res.set(float(a) / float(b) if b else "ERROR")


# Configuracion de la raiz
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bd=15)

# Variables para los campos de texto
n1 = tk.StringVar()
n2 = tk.StringVar()
res = tk. StringVar()

n1.trace_add("write", resolver)
n2.trace_add("write", resolver)

# Opciones con las operaciones
op = tk.StringVar(value="suma")
op.trace_add("write", resolver)

rb_frame = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=3)
rb_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=True, side="top", pady=(0, 10))
tk.Radiobutton(
    rb_frame, text="Sumar", variable=op, value="suma"
    ).pack(side="left")
tk.Radiobutton(
    rb_frame, text="Restar", variable=op, value="resta"
    ).pack(side="left")
tk.Radiobutton(
    rb_frame, text="Multiplicar", variable=op, value="mult"
    ).pack(side="left")
tk.Radiobutton(
    rb_frame, text="Dividir", variable=op, value="div"
    ).pack(side="left")

# Crear campos de texto
tk.Label(root, text="Número 1").pack()
tk.Entry(
    root, justify="center", textvariable=n1
    ).pack()

tk.Label(root, text="Número 2").pack()
tk.Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=n2).pack()

tk.Label(root, text="\nResultado").pack()
tk.Entry(
    root, justify="center", textvariable=res, state="disabled"
    ).pack()
    
# Botón para borrado
tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=borrar).pack(pady=(10, 0))

# Bucle pricnipal de la aplicación
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]